# How long does Google take for the rating stars to show up in the SERP?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have a rated page since 10 days ago, and the rating starts are still not showing in SERP.

[Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbiologiainteresante.com%2Fbiomedicina%2F105%2Fcrean-nanorobots-capaces-de-combatir-las-celulas-cancerigenas%2F) is not showing any errors.

Should I wait some more time? How long does Google usually take for the rating stars to show up in SERP?

Comment: You need to wait, no one can tell you when Googlebot will crawl your page and apply changes into SERPs.

Comment: @Zistoloen - All right, thanks. Do you have any experience on adding ratings to pages? If yes, how long does it usually take for you the first time you add a rating to a page? It would be good to know.

Comment: It's different for all sites. Even if I tell you how long it took for my sites, it won't be relevant.

Comment: As this question is older, can you tell, how much time did it took to show your ratings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is revalant information found on Google's Webmaster Tools FAQ regarding rich data.

> [SOURCE](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets)
>
> Q: *Why doesn't my site show rich snippets?*
>
> A: Google does not guarantee that Rich
>   Snippets will show up for search results from a particular site even
>   if structured data is marked up and can be extracted successfully
>   according to the testing tool. Here are some reasons that marked-up
>   pages might not be shown with Rich Snippets:
>
> Q: *How long does it take for rich snippets to be visible?*
>
> A: Once you've marked up your site's content, Google will discover it
>   the next time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for
>   rich snippets to appear in search results, if we do choose to display
>   rich snippets for your site). If you're marking up your content for
>   rich snippets, you can let us know. Google won't be able to
>   individually reply to your message, but we may use the information you
>   supply to improve our detection and display of marked-up content.

Answer (score 0):

Google claims the quality of site determines if snippets appear or not - even if snippets are implemented correctly.